# Could the Jensen-Shannon divergence and Kullback-Leibler divergence be used as loss functions of non-generation problems?

Tags: deep-learning, optimization, objective-functions, generative-adversarial-networks

If I understand correctly, the KL divergence is a measure of information loss between a ground truth distribution $P$ and a predicted distribution $Q$, and the Jensen-Shannon divergence is the mean of the KL Divergences of 2 cases

1. Predicted distribution is mean of $P$ and $Q$, and ground truth is $P$
2. Predicted distribution is mean of $P$ and $Q$, and ground truth is $Q$

Since KL divergence can be easily interpreted as information loss in $Q$ relative to $P$, what can JS divergence interpret-ably represent? I cannot see any use cases of these measures unless there are two distributions to compare. Is there any other problem where I could use them as loss functions other than generation problems? If so how, and why?

Comment: this is a duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117225/jensen-shannon-divergence-vs-kullback-leibler-divergence, if you look there i hope it helps

Comment: @mshlis Why should this be a duplicate of that?